# How to execute SQL queries inside MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am developing an application using Django framework. As you may know the workflow is you first describe your objects in Python classes and then you synchronize the database.

I made a MySQL Workbench EER diagram. Since then I continued to develop the application, so the database model is not updated in the EER diagram nor the MySQL Workbench model.

I tried to synchronize it using the built-in feature "Synchronize with Any Source" of MySQL Workbench, but this feature is not working for some reason and causes a segmentation fault. The queries to be executed inside the MySQL Workbench model are displayed but at the last step I get an empty SQL alter script. I tried manually copying the queries in that script and clicking the "Execute" button, but I had no luck with that. I think MySQL stores queries internally. Anyway. I submitted the bug to MySQL Workbench developers [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66707) and now it is fixed, but not yet released. I am now looking for a workaround while waiting for the next release.

*Although I have a specific problem, the question remains generic.*

**Is it possible to execute queries on the MySQL Workbench model in order to alter it?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "**[Forward Engineer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering.html)**" option? It allows you to reflect all the changes that were made to your table relations directly to the database which is a pretty useful functionality.

There are some catches though like the inability to maintain existing data every time forward engineering is performed however this can be compensated by entering some example data which will be shipped with the ER diagram the next time you perform "Forward engineer".

Comment: I need to reflect changes from database to the model which is the opposite of "Forward Engineer" option. I tried the "Reverse Engineer" option but it fails saying  that tables exist already.